# Write a line to a file line from a struct with a handful of members

Tags: c, string, file, struct, fputs

```
typedef struct
{
char name[64];
int balance;
int gain;
}
Player;
"%s\t%d\t%d\n", p.name, p.balance, p.gain ;
```

I'm trying to input this into my file and I'm wondering if there is any way that I could make that into one string so it will work with fputs();

````
count = 0;
    while ((fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        count++;

        /* If current line is line to replace */
        if (count == line)
            fputs("%s\t%d\t%d\n", p.name, p.balance, p.gain,fTemp);
        else
            fputs(buffer, fTemp);
    }
```
````

Comment: What's wrong with `fprintf`?

Comment: That is the format, that is now in the post, is what my friend and I are to use it to get it to update a specific line in a text file; however, when trying to use `fprintf()` it does not like that

Comment: Code in comments just looks unreadable. Edit your question to include it there and you can apply formatting.

Comment: Hint: `fprintf` *not* `fputs`.

Comment: We just weren't updating balance itself in the function, so fprintf was working when we were using it just not updating. Thank you for saying that `fprintf` should work.